# "Performance in the office" vs "performance at the office."

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

What's the correct option? Maybe both are okay?

Example sentence:

> Research has shown that naps improve mood, focus, memory, which translates into better performance **in/at** the office.

(*[Performance in the office](https://www.google.com.tw/search?client=ubuntu&hs=Dzb&biw=1454&bih=954&tbm=bks&ei=x1qCXLbSFq2Nr7wP1rGKwAE&q=%22%20performance%20in%20the%20office%22&oq=%22%20performance%20in%20the%20office%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...196010.196075.0.196322.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.MDkYfxg6EOM)* has more Google results than *[permanence at the office](https://www.google.com.tw/search?client=ubuntu&hs=9yb&biw=894&bih=954&tbm=bks&ei=w1qCXLnZF5WUr7wP_6a1QA&q=%22%20performance%20at%20the%20office%22&oq=%22%20performance%20at%20the%20office%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...2751.2751.0.2915.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.0pxo8zAFvcA)*. But I wonder if that says anything.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Google ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=performance%20in%20the%20office%2Cperformance%20at%20the%20office&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cperformance%20in%20the%20office%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cperformance%20at%20the%20office%3B%2Cc0) suggests that "in the office" is significantly preferred, but I think both would be equally understood and acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

Both would generally be considered acceptable in that particular sentence.

---

However, one preposition is clearly better than another in certain constructions:

> ✔ He was comfortable **in** the office *of president*.
>   ✘ He was comfortable **at** the office *of president*.

In this construction, *office* is being used to define a role, not a location, so *in* is idiomatic, whereas *at* is not.

> ✔ He was comfortable wearing shorts **at** the office *party*.
>   ✘ He was comfortable wearing shorts **in** the office *party*.

Here, *office* is being used as part of a compound noun. An *office party* is something you can be *at* but not *in*.

---

Note how your original sentence changes if you replace *the office* with *work*:

> ✔ It translates into better performance **at** work.
>   ✘ It translates into better performance **in** work.

---

And in the original sentence, there can a subtle difference in meaning (although it's not always interpreted that way):

> ✔ Research has shown that naps improve mood, focus, memory, which translates into better performance **in** the office.

Here, it is talking about the performance of someone while they are working. They have clocked in, so to speak, and are engaged at making a living.

> ✔ Research has shown that naps improve mood, focus, memory, which translates into better performance **at** the office.

Here, it is talking about the performance of someone who is physically at their job site. They may or may not be actually on the clock, but they are located where their job would have them be working.

---

Of course, both sentences carry both meanings. But the preposition used has it lean slightly more one way than the other.